# Using a C++ Qt5 plugin in python

Tags: python, qt, plugins, qt5, pyqt5

I have written a plugin in Qt5/C++. I use this plugin via `QPluginLoader` in my C++ application. However, I would like to use the plugin in python.

How can in use this plugin in a python qt5 application?

Comment: I do not know about pyqt, but in PySide2 (the official python bindings supported by the Qt company) you can simply import the `QPluginLoader` class in python and use it the same way as in c++

Comment: @Felix Have you actually tried this? The docs for [QPluginLoader::instance()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpluginloader.html#instance) state that `qobject_cast()` is required to access the interfaces of the plugin. So it's not simply a matter of importing the `QPluginLoader` class. In PyQt, it might be possible to use [sip.cast()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html) instead of `qobject_cast()`, but it's not clear how you would specify a custom type that PyQt doesn't know about.

Comment: I tried loading a plugin and got a valid object from instance(), but I did not try casting. However If you take a look at the src of [`object_cast`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h#n525) you can see that it is basically just a `reinterpret_cast` with additional typecheckes. So `sip.cast` should work. The custom type must be made available to python just like any other c++ type - you can do so for PySide2 via [shiboken](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/shiboken2/) - or however you would do it in pyqt

Comment: @Felix So, as I suspected, you ***can't*** simply use it in the same way as in C++, because you also need to create separate python bindings for the custom type. But once you've done that, you might just as well just import the custom type and instantiate it directly. The plugin would be redundant.

Comment: Not exactly. You have to bind the *interface* class, not the actual plugin *implementation*. However, properties, signals, slots and invokable methods can always be accessed via the meta system, without having to do anything of this

Comment: @Felix Either way, you need to create a separate set of python bindings if you want to use the plugin *in exactly the same way* as you would in C++.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you do not want to do this, I would recommend making everything in the interface invokable and write a python wrapper class around the meta calls, if needed

Comment: Some time ago I tried to load a plugin with QPluginLoader but having no reference to the class I could not use the methods of the class since QPluginLoader only returned a QObject, so I see that you must create wrappers instead of wanting to load the plugin.